# How would I convert this to a multi-dimensional array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How would I convert this table to a multi-dimensional array in javascript?

[image]

Comment: I think you are missing some code.

Answer (score 2):

Use an object with the flag names as keys, and arrays of booleans as values.

```
var table = {
    "STAT": [ false, false, false, true, true, false ]
    // etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
[
    [ 'PATIENT_RESULT_IN_RANGE', [ 1, 0, 1 ] ],
    [ 'QC_RESULT_IN_RANGE', [ 1, , 0, 1 ] ],
    [ 'QC_DUE', [ 0, , , 1, 1, 1 ] ]
    // ect.
]
```

or

```
{
    'PATIENT_RESULT_IN_RANGE': [ 1, 0, 1 ],
    'QC_RESULT_IN_RANGE': [ 1, , 0, 1 ],
    'QC_DUE': [ 0, , , 1, 1, 1 ]
    // ect.
}
```

I wouldn't use the stars (empty values) though...

Comment: They're not empty values; the description states the star means to repeat the value from the previous column :)